# Using ios-charts in Swift for ios7+

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am trying to use this charting library which is a port of the same library I use for Android:

https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts

Since i use Swift targeting ios7+ I decided to follow this guide:

> If you want to compile for iOS 7:
>
> Drag the code itself (.swift files) to your project. As sadly, Swift currently does not support compiling Frameworks for iOS 7.
>   Make sure that the files are added to the Target membership.

So I have done basicly placed a copy of the entire ios-charts folder in my project folder next to my own .swift files.

Then removed all units but .swift but keeping the file/directory structure. Interestingly, I can not change/add targets for any of the files in the folder since the option does not show itself when clicking the .swift files in xcode.

I then drop an UIView and change class to e.g. BarChartView.

I create an outlet so I have this in my class definition:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myStickChart: BarChartView!
```

However, I when building I am getting error

> use of undeclared type "BarChartView

This is probably a simple problem, but this is the first 3rd party library I have to use.

I have experiemented with pods before, but decided against it - I would rather, for now as long as I am targeting ios7, be able to drag in he untts I want to use like descrived in the instructions for ios-charts with swift/ios7

[image]

Comment: maybe a silly question - but you have `include ios-charts` in your class definition?

Comment: I have expanded my question now - if that was no wha you meant, could you post an example? (I have included all the .swift files in my ios7+ swift project and associated them to all my targets)

Comment: according to the github link you provide, you need to include `@import Charts` in your swift class file

Comment: When installed that way yes, but I use the ios7 compatible mehod "Drag the code itself (.swift files) to your project. As sadly, Swift currently does not support compiling Frameworks for iOS 7. Make sure that the files are added to the Target membership."

Comment: well, I managed to get it working for iOS 7 - but it's a bit tedious.  I will add a new answer to demonstrate ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implementing this library for iOS 7 has it's own special challenges.  The instructions advise you to *Drag the code itself (.swift files) to your project* - and when I did that at first I dragged over the top-level folder (like you would) but I couldn't get it to work.

Then I copied over each group of files individually - I put them all in the same folder `Charts`, but I guess you could recreate the folder structure.

Now I have a simple project working with `Charts`, `iOS 7`, and with no need for `import`

Just to be clear - here's how the file structure looks in my project - not very elegant, but it works.
[image: Chart files]

Answer (score 2):

@Tom - I use the same classes in one of my projects, and I installed it in exactly the same way as you do.  I can generate the same errors that you're seeing - but only if I remove `import Charts` from my class definition.

Here's what the start of my class definition looks like

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class SharePriceGraphViewController: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate
{
    var myStickChart: BarChartView!  // I don't really have this - added for this test :-)
```

as it stands, this compiles nicely.  if I remove the import - I get the same error as you do.

Comment: If I add "import Charts" I get "No such module 'Charts' - but I also read the iso-charts instructions such as if installing for iso7/swift (as opposed to ios8+) ignore the normal install instructions and drag in the .swift the files like I described in my original post. Hence I have not dragged in / added any "charts" project since that's not the ios-charts instructions? But maybe I am wrong, if so, I find it quite confusing... (Good for SO then)

Comment: Did you as me also only add the .swift files or did you start with "Drag the Charts.xcodeproj to your project. Go to your target's settings, hit the "+" under the "Embedded Binaries" section, and select the Charts.framework" - if so, does your project work with ios7?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work on ios7.  When I try, it fails, but because of the other frameworks I have in that project.  I will try to create a simple version, but it will be later tonight (UK time)

Answer (score 0):

**Following steps worked for me:**

1. install via cocoapods by using `pod 'Charts'`
2. Now if you will try to write anything related to `charts` it will not read that file or class and you will see the error like `use of undeclared type xxxxx`. So for this **GoTo ⇾ Project Target ⇾ General ⇾ Linked Frameworks and Libraries ⇾ Click on + button** and add `Charts.framework`.
3. Go to your class where you want to use this. `import Charts` and now
   you will be able to use this framework without any error.

Comment: Yes, but frameworks don't work in iOS 7 the way Charts uses them, so that method doesn't work in iOS 7. See https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/tree/v2.2.5#usage ;)